# VBA / Access: How is a DAO record set represented?

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, resultset, recordset

Maybe this question is quite basic, but I think it's important to understand it.

Assuming we perform a database query which will result in a result set looking like this:

```
[A1][B1][C1][D1][E1][F1]

[A2][B2][C2][D2][E2][F2]

[A3][B3][C3][D3][E3][F3]
```

So, index NUMBER is the representing the row, index LETTER is representing the column.

So, would the result set be an array?

How could I e.g. access the second row?

Comment: Interestingly enough the record is kind of an array. If you store it in an array using .getrows method the output is actually transposed. This was kind of frustrating to know at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access the third column(0,1,2)

```
recordset.fields(2)
```

or

```
recordset.fields("fieldName")
```

go to the next record(row)

```
recordset.movenext
```

move to a specific record

```
recordset.move
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you'd access a particular record

```
rs.MoveFirst
rs.Move 2
```

or

```
dim TestValue as long
TestValue = 2
Do While True
    If rs!TestField = TestValue Then Exit Do
    rs.MoveNext
    If rs.EOF then Exit Do
Loop
```

or

```
 rs.AbsolutePosition = 2
```